# Set radial gradient as window background

Tags: android, background, window, drawable, gradient

I have the following gradient_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="200"
        android:startColor="#666666"
        android:endColor="#AAAAAA"
        />
</shape>
```

I would like to use this gradient as the `android:windowBackground` setting for my application. The application would then have a few views with transparent backgrounds on top of it.

I've tried applying this gradient directly using:

`android:windowBackground="@drawable/gradient_bg"`

within my application manifest, and then setting the scrollview background as transparent, but I just get the default black background.

How would I go about achieving this result? I specifically don't want to apply the background to the scrollview.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way might be to create a theme (in values/styles.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="windowbg" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/rectangle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now you can add this theme to your activity/application like this:

```
android:theme="@style/windowbg"
```

Comment: I've used this to get the effect, this should do it!

Comment: Can you please suggest, how can I define this "windowBackground" style progrmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a bitmap from shape. So create antoher xml in which you relate to your shape. Some example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```